# Use 'any' to find if a string contains part of list, then make that found part into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of potential hits in a dictionary. I would like to get user input, then search the dictionary to see if any of the words are found in the string. If one is (doesn't matter which) I want to assign that found word a variable. I just can't figure out the last part; storing the found element into a variable. So if I type "tell me about horus" it will grab the keyword 'horus' and print info from that value in the dictionary.

```
lookup_dict = {'horus': "description of Horus.", 'anubis': "description of Anubis."}

userin = input(":  ")
res = any(ele in userin for ele in lookup_dict)
if res is True:
    # somehow print the description from the associated element
```

Comment: You need to split `userin` into a list of words.

Comment: Ah dang, I was hoping to avoid that. Splitting looks like alien gibberish to me.

Comment: What if more than one word is found?

Comment: Get used to it: `userin = input(": ").split()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just care if the word is part of the input string, and don't mind if two or more words are in the input string:

```
lookup_dict = {'horus': "description of Horus.", 'anubis': "description of Anubis."}

userin = input(":  ")
for word, definition in lookup_dict.items():
    if word in userin:
        print(definition)
```

Comment: You need to split the input.

Comment: Probably better to loop over the input than the dictionary. The input is probably smaller, and searching a dictionary is O(1)

Comment: split is not needed

Comment: No need to split if OP just wants to check if the word in the dictionary is *somewhere* in the input string, as I pointed out.

Comment: If you don't split, then the word `cat` will match `category`.

Comment: Which is why I started my answer with the disclaimer.

Comment: This is actually a lot more what I was looking to do, thank you! The dictionary is only a few entries (like 10 or less) at any time, and I really just need the first match found. Thanks!

Comment: Good Solution no need to iteration in key  @jfaccioni

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
lookup_dict = {'horus': "description of Horus.", 'anubis': "description of Anubis."}

userin = input(":  ").split(" ")
for i in userin:
    if i in lookup_dict.keys():
        print(lookup_dict[i])
```

Comment: You don't need `.keys()`

Comment: I think your original solution was better.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution to your question is to loop over all *keys* in the dictionary, checking if they appear in the string that is input by the user. Note that by default python iterates over the keys (try `for key in lookup_dict: print(key)`), we can use `.items()` to loop over tuples of `(key, value)`.

```py
lookup_dict = {'horus': "description of Horus.", 'anubis': "description of Anubis."}

userin = input(":  ")

for key, value in lookup_dict.items():
    # Checks if substring `key` appears in `userin`
    if key in userin:
        print(value)
```

You might not care if the user writes *Horus* or *horus*, in which case you can use `.lower()` on the string `userin`. If you want to get even more fancy, you can use regular expressions using the python standard library `re` module, which is basically a mini-language specifically made for matching strings. (Check out https://regexr.com/ to play around.) The example might then look like this:

```py
import re 
# Will match Horus or horus but must have one whitespace after the word 
# anubis must be matched directly, we have not used any special regex methods 
lookup_dict = {'[hH]orus\s': "description of Horus.", 'anubis': "description of Anubis."} 
userin = input(":  ") 

for key, value in lookup_dict.items(): 
    # Checks if regex `key` appears anywhere in `userin` 
    if re.search(key, userin): 
        print(value)
```